# svn merge --reintegrate fails on "missing ranges"

Tags: svn, merge, conflict, svn-reintegrate

The situation is like this:

A team worked on long-term feature branch (18 months). Periodically merging trunk back to this feature branch (at the beginning every month, later every two/three months).

Today we want to merge the feature branch back to trunk, using the reintegrate feature.

The problem is that we get a lot (thousands!) of:

```
branches/feature/dir/file.foo
Missing ranges: /trunk/dir/file.foo:94959
```

But, when I'm checking the svn log, I can see that range 94000-96500 was indeed merged some time in the past.

What is happening here?
Why svn is complaining on "missing ranges" if it is not true? 
Can there be a reason that r94959 will be missing if I see merge info on 94000-96500?
How can I fix this (as i said we're talking about thousands of revisions "missing")?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This normally happens in a following scenario:

1. Your trunk had a some two branches like `branch1` and `branch2` working parallely.
2. `branch1` created first and then `branch2` created. But, `branch2` changes completed first and those are reintegrated to trunk.
3. After that before the reintegrating `branch1`, we need to do an `svn merge` (not `svn merge --reintegrate`) from trunk to `branch1` and resolve the conflicts.
4. And during this, we may get some folders also with changes in properties with an update in some `merge-info`. If we, don't commit these folders since these are just `merge-info` property changes only, then it can cause a similar issue in during `reintegrate` merge of `branch1`.

If this is your scenario, the solution you can try is to do an `svn merge` from your trunk to `branch1` again and you will get your `merge-info` properties updated in your folders again and commit those to `branch1`. Then, try again with `svn merge --reintegrate` from `branch1` to trunk.

Comment: Anyway to do this without svn merge? My reintegrate source branch is a release branch, I can't do svn merge now and check in new stuff into the reintegrate source branch!

Comment: @endless : Reintegration is a specific action where you have been bringing trunk in (e.g. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html). If that isn't your situation, you need to do a merge back to trunk instead of a reintegration.